# how do I create amazon ec2 instance with iam profile via php?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'd like to know how to create a new amazon ec2 instance using the php sdk and to do so providing it a IAM profile for a given role upon startup.

This is a new feature apparently, and consequently the real world examples are sparse at this time.  Any help would be appreciated, the link from Amazon below is tempting, but skips over the part of actually creating the instance with a IAM profile assigned from SDK and instead uses the management console (which defeats the whole purpose, right?).

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSdkDocsPHP/latest/DeveloperGuide/php-dg-roles.html

I'm assuming its an option of run_instances, but i suppose it could be via IAM object instead?

Thanks,

R

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is the SDK Answer based on what ended up working for me:

```
$options = array(
            'InstanceType'=>$this->instance_size,
            'KeyName'=>'my key',
            'SecurityGroup'=>'mysecgroup',
            'UserData' => base64_encode($user_data_contents),
                'Placement' => array(
            'AvailabilityZone' => $this->availability_zone
            ),

      'IamInstanceProfile' => array(
                'Arn' => 'arn:aws:iam::9999999999999:instance-profile/yourIAMNameHere'
                )

        );
```

Not a particular hard answer in retrospect - I include here to help get the SDK documentation pumped up a bit since this is a new function for EC2